# Name mismatch in ticket

Tags: tickets

My fathers name is R.Gurusamy but, while booking, I put it in as Gurusamy Ramachandran (a reference to his father, my grandfather). Will the airport authority accept this or will it be a problem?

Comment: I've booked a ticket for a friend and spelled his last name incorrectly.  The airline fixed it.  Call the airline.

Comment: Please provide more details like which country is this question for? And whether travel is domestic or international?

Comment: At least in the US, the name must match exactly, and it cannot be changed (although we were able to make obvious corrections right after buying). Contact the airline now and get it adjusted. You will not be able to fix it anymore when you are at the airport for flying. - other countries might have other rules.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not exactly clear what the situation is.  Is the problem with the First or Last name?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so there will be an issue at airport if at all if the security or airport authorities ask you about the name you or he can show the photo ID or any GOVT proof. Is this ticket for domestic or International?